Inverse MouseWheelZoom
There is a project that uses openlayers and react.
I came across the need to invert the direction of the mouse wheel when zooming. More precisely, even be able to switch from standard mode to inverted and back.
I tried using the code from this question, but I still get map jumps.
(github)
Perhaps there is an easier way?
I also tried this option:


let mouseWheelInt = new MouseWheelZoom({
  constrainResolution: true,
  onFocusOnly: true,
  useAnchor: true
});

map.addInteraction(mouseWheelInt);
mouseWheelInt.setActive(false);

window.addEventListener('wheel', (event) => {
  event.stopImmediatePropagation();

  let delta = 0;
  if (wheel_orient === "Inverse") {
    delta = event.deltaY > 0 ? 1 : -1;
  } else {
    delta = event.deltaY < 0 ? 1 : -1;
  }

  let view = map.getView();

  const currentZoom = Math.round(view.getZoom());
  if (currentZoom === undefined) {
    return;
  }

  const newZoom = view.getConstrainedZoom(currentZoom + delta);
  if (newZoom == currentZoom) {
    return;
  }

  if (view.getAnimating()) {
    view.cancelAnimations();
  }

  const coordinates = view.getCenter();

  view.animate({
    zoom: newZoom,
    anchor: coordinates,
    duration: 250,
    easing: easeOut
  });
}, false);




You could patch the interaction code https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/main/src/ol/interaction/MouseWheelZoom.js#L260 (or create a subclass) to sensibly handle negative value of the maxDelta option
handleWheelZoom_(map) {
  const view = map.getView();
  if (view.getAnimating()) {
    view.cancelAnimations();
  }
  let delta =
    ((this.maxDelta_ > 0 ? -1 : 1) *
      clamp(
        this.totalDelta_,
        -Math.abs(this.maxDelta_) * this.deltaPerZoom_,
        Math.abs(this.maxDelta_) * this.deltaPerZoom_,
      )) /
    this.deltaPerZoom_;
  if (view.getConstrainResolution() || this.constrainResolution_) {
    // view has a zoom constraint, zoom by 1
    delta = delta ? (delta > 0 ? 1 : -1) : 0;
  }
  zoomByDelta(view, delta, this.lastAnchor_, this.duration_);

  this.mode_ = undefined;
  this.totalDelta_ = 0;
  this.lastAnchor_ = null;
  this.startTime_ = undefined;
  this.timeoutId_ = undefined;
};

Working example https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-behq56?file=package.json,index.html,index.js

Mike, hello!
You help me out again, thank you :)
